# Creating a (good) struct from a javascript typed array?

Tags: javascript, typed-arrays

I'm thinking about typed arrays in javascript; in particular, reading binary file headers. Reading the [MDN Typed Arrays documentation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Typed_arrays), they blithely say we can represent the C struct:

```
struct someStruct {
  unsigned long id;
  char username[16];
  float amountDue;
};
```

with the javascript:

```
var buffer = new ArrayBuffer(24);

// ... read the data into the buffer ...

var idView = new Uint32Array(buffer, 0, 1);
var usernameView = new Uint8Array(buffer, 4, 16);
var amountDueView = new Float32Array(buffer, 20, 1);
```

and then you can say `amountDueView[0]` but seem oblivious to the fact that treating a scalar as a one-element array is terrible and being able to say something like `sizeof(someStruct)` is useful as well.

So... is there something better? MDN makes reference to [js-ctypes](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Mozilla/js-ctypes) but it's no standard javascript.

Edit: Yes, I know about javascript objects. Modeling the data isn't the problem; reading and writing binary data elegantly is.

Comment: You will want to have a look at [`DataView`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/DataView). Btw, from what I read js-ctypes are a library wrapper on standard javascript, so it should be save (and easy) to use.

Comment: you would want to composite the arrays into an object with it's own ArrayBuffer, and possibly add some getters onto the properties to avoid the extra "[0]" each time.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

For what it's worth, there's [jBinary](https://github.com/jDataView/jBinary), which lets you do stuff like:

```
var binary_data = '\x0f\x00\x00\x00Bruce\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\xecQXA';

var myTypeset = {
    'jBinary.all': 'someStruct',
    'jBinary.littleEndian': true,
    someStruct: {
        id: 'uint32',
        username: ['string0', 16],
        amountDue: 'float'
    }
};

var binary = new jBinary(binary_data, myTypeset);
header = binary.readAll(); // Object {id: 15, username: "Bruce", amountDue: 13.520000457763672}

header.username = "Jim";
binary.writeAll(header);
binary.readAll(); // Object {id: 15, username: "Jim", amountDue: 13.520000457763672}
```

It's not particularly well-documented (an example like the above would be very welcome) but it's quite good.

The biggest caveat is that it relies on javascript objects having properties remain in the order they're defined, which is practically the case but not part of the javascript spec. I suspect this will never actually change because it would break a kajillion things, but still.

Comment: can't believe this is the only example on SO with `jbinary`. Thank you ! Do you know if it can read from an `arrayBuffer` (or typedarray, same thing) instead of a string ?

Comment: I'm quite sure it does; you'll need to try though.

Answer (score 0):

Can't you just define an object in JS to model this?

```
var someObject =  {
  Id:2,
  username: [],
  amountDue:5
};
```

Comment: he can, but will that mount the header of a binary file in the same way?

Answer (score -4):

You more than likely don't need typed arrays for your application; the rest of the world has been surviving just fine without them. `IE < 10` doesn't even support them.

You can write the object like this

```
var data = {id: 123, username: "bob", amountDue: 123.45};
```

And read from it like this

```
data.id;
// 123

data.username;
// "bob"
```

Try to read an unset key

```
data.foo;
// undefined
```

And set a key after it's defined

```
data.foo = "bar";
// "bar"
```

And delete the key

```
delete data.foo;
// true
```

Try to read a deleted key

```
data.foo;
// undefined
```

Comment: I think you're missing the fact that the OP is reading some binary data (which has a C-like binary format) into a ArrayBuffer and then trying to interpret that data in javascript.  This problem isn't just about statically declared javascript data.

Comment: Yes -- I'm not interested in doing this for performance reasons, but to read (and write) binary data structures elegantly.